# as3 accessing XML data randomly

Tags: xml, arrays, actionscript-3

After reading data from XML source I like to be able to show one random item from data  whenever, say, clicked a button. I think I can accomplish this by storing the data into an array and use it from the array.
I would like to learn if  possible to do it directly from xml without storing it into another array. Thanks in advance

```
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("XML_NOTES.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);


function processXML(e:Event):void {
            var loader:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader;
            var myXML:XML = new XML(loader.data);
            for (i=0;i<2;i++){
            trace(myXML.LEMMA[i]);
            array.push(myXML.LEMMA[i]);
            }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this directly from myXML variable, you would need to set myXML as a global variable:

```
var myXML:XML;
var myXMLLoader:URLLoader = new URLLoader();
myXMLLoader.load(new URLRequest("XML_NOTES.xml"));
myXMLLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, processXML);

function processXML(e:Event):void {
    var loader:URLLoader = e.target as URLLoader;
    myXML = new XML(loader.data);
}

function getRandomItem():XML {
    var elementsCount:int = myXML.LEMMA.length();
    var randomIndex:int = Math.floor( Math.random() * (elementsCount-1) );
    return myXML.LEMMA[randomIndex];
}
```

Comment: Do I need to use event.complete not to face loading problem or not

Comment: Yes, it's necessary because in this event you get your xml content.

Comment: I have edited my code to let you see how it all may look like

Comment: -1 Global variables are generally bad practice.  Avoid them at all costs.  In this case, for certain, there is no good reason for `myXML` to be global.

Comment: @ Brian: How can we reach the data if myXML is not global... Do you have any suggestion to get it work?

Comment: @VladimirTsvetkov I am responding to the statement "you would need to set myXML as a global variable".  If that goes, I'll take back my -1.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly:

```
function processXML(event:Event):void
{
    var myXML:XML = XML((e.target as URLLoader).data);
    var children:XMLList = myXML.*;
    trace(children[Math.random() * children.length()].toXMLstring());
}
```

Note that although it's called XML *List*, it's actually an array, more yet, it's a true array (dense), unlike the Array class :) (which is a mix of an array and string hash). So there's no problem accessing an element by index - no need to convert to array.